# Cologne for men?

Tags: halacha, rabbis, men-male, smell

The Gemara [brochois 43b](http://halakhah.com/berakoth/berakoth_43.html) and [rambam daiot 5.9](http://chabad.org/910345/) quoted below writes that a Talmid Chacham should not wear cologne (a scent).
Does this apply nowadays?
I've personally smelled a Rosh Yeshiva's strong scent of cologne.

> [Before going out] he smears it (the scented oil from havdolo) **on the head of the attendant; and if the attendant is a man of learning, he smears it on the wall,** since it is unbecoming for a scholar to go abroad scented (so that people should not suspect him of homosexual acts).
>   Our Rabbis taught: **Six things are unbecoming for a scholar. He should not go abroad scented;** he should not go out by night alone; he should not go abroad in patched sandals; he should not converse with a woman in the street; he should not take a set meal in the company of ignorant persons; and he should not be the last to enter the Beth ha-Midrash. Some add that he should not take long strides nor carry himself stiffly.
>   '**He should not go abroad scented**'. R. Abba the son of R. Hiyya b. Abba said in the name of R. Johanan: This applies only to a place where people are suspected of pederasty. R. Shesheth said: This applies only to [the scenting of] one's clothes; but [perfuming] the body removes the perspiration. R. Papa said: The hair is on the same footing as clothes; others, however, say: as the body.

[Audio](http://download.dafyomi.org/content/dafyomi/mp3/brachos/brachos_043b.mp3) 18:00

Rambam

> ...He should not go out in the marketplace perfumed, or with perfumed clothes, nor should he put perfume on his hair. However, he is permitted to rub perfume on his body if he does so in order to remove filth...

Comment: Where does the Gemara write this? Were the Rosh Yeshivas you smelled Talmidei Chachamim?

Comment: מלבוש תלמיד חכם מלבוש נאה ונקי. ואסור לו שימצא בבגדו כתם או שמנונית וכיוצא בהן. ולא ילבש לא מלבוש מלכים כגון בגדי זהב וארגמן שהכל מסתכלין בהן. ולא מלבוש עניים שהוא מבזה את לובשיו אלא בגדים בינונים נאים. ולא יהא בשרו נראה מתחת מדיו כמו בגדי הפשתן הקלים ביותר שעושים במצרים. ולא יהיו בגדיו סחובין על הארץ כמו בגדי גסי הרוח אלא עד עקבו ובית יד שלו עד ראשי אצבעותיו. ולא ישלשל טליתו מפני שנראה כגסות הרוח אלא בשבת בלבד אם אין לו להחליף. ולא ינעל מנעלים מטולאים טלאי על גבי טלאי בימות החמה.. לא יצא מבושם לשוק ולא בבגדים מבושמים ולא ישים בושם בשערו. אבל אם משח בשרו בבושם כדי להעביר את הזוהמא מותר.

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=30722&rid=137

Comment: Thanks Preferred. Do any modern poskim talk about this?

Comment: א יצא מבושם לשוק ולא בבגדים מבושמים ולא ישים בושם בשערו. דבריו תמוהים שבברכות (מ"ג.) נראה שהאסור רק במקום שחשודים על משכב זכר אבל לדידן הלוא לא חשודים וכמבואר ברמב"ם פרק כ"א דאסו"ב (הי"ד). 
אמנם נראה שת"ח חייב ליזהר יותר, ומאחר דמסקינן בברכות שם דת"ח אל יצא יחידי מפני חשש זנות, הלוא עליו לחוש אף לחשש רחוק, ולכן אין להתבשם שיחשדוהו שמתגרה בנשים.

Comment: In that case, Yishaq, was the _rosh y'shiva_ outdoors when you smelled him?

Comment: Is there such a thing as a תלמיד חכם today?

Comment: @SethJ With regards to the *halachos* of public comportment, the term "תלמיד חכם" is defined to include people who may be viewed or regarded as Torah scholars by others (see, for e.g., [here](http://www.torah.org/learning/ravfrand/5761/emor.html) and [here](http://www.dinonline.org/2010/06/17/todays-talmid-chacham-and-his-ways/)).

Comment: Cologne is Koln,  a town in Germany.  At the time of Gemara they used oils. דשנת בשמן ראשי כוסי רוויה

Comment: No need to edit others' questions excessively. In contemporary American English it is called cologne; not eau de Cologne,  and it is a bona fide word; not a mere colloquialism, regardless of the etymology. | It is no more incorrect to state the the Gemara references it, than to state the Gemara references any other word in English; a language which did not exist in the time of the Gemara.

Comment: Is it a beged ishah issue?

Comment: @DonielF I think it is an issue of being suspected in homosexually

Comment: @mevaqesh, Kouty's point is (in line with my edit) that cologne was not used in the times of chazal, or IIRC, any other modern methods of applying scents.

Comment: FWIW, my grandfather ז”ל was a chazzan and he received at least a few gifts of cologne from bar mitzvah bochurim he'd taught over the years (I don't know whether he used them, but he maintained them and we've kept them since he died, albeit without using them ourselves )

Comment: Practicality, perhaps. No offense to Talmidei Chachamim, in general, but a number of my rebbeim in high school probably would have benefitted from using cologne! Smelling from sweat and such is both uncomfortable and disrespectful to the students. The classrooms were sometimes immensely hot, so it was almost impossible NOT to shvitz during the day. Wouldn't it be not just permissible but recommended that in such circumstances, Talmidei Chachamim use cologne?

Comment: @hazoriz If you would like to increase the likelihood that this question gets good answers, I recommend that you [edit] it, at a minimum, to include the requisite gemara citation and quotation.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I did not ask it, if since you told me I will

Comment: @hazoriz Anyone (wich sufficient rep) can edit posts here. You've posted a bounty, indicating that you want answers. I'm recommending additional steps that could help you achieve your apparent goal.

Comment: @IsaacMoses thank you I appreciate your help

Comment: Given that the above citation confirms my previous thinking that a Talmid Chacham may were cologne to prevent perspiration odor, then if you noticed the scent, how would you know the reason why he is using the cologne?

Comment: Since this might not be quite an answer (in the sense of explaining the RY) I'll start with posting here:

There's a distinction between using deodorant for hygienic purposes versus applying perfume for the sake of being "sexy". The former surely is particulary important for a talmid chacham but the latter is uniquely unbecoming, and there is no reason for this simple principle to change during any subsequent generation. So it would seem that RY was in the wrong.

Comment: Then again, it seems plenty of other guidelines cited in the same chapter in the Rambam are widely disregarded by many rabbis, and perhaps the fact that these instructions appear in הלכות דעות and as far as I can tell are omitted in Shulchan Aruch has led many to determine that they are only of an advisory, but not quite binding nature.

Comment: Here is a contemporary teshuva on the subject: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=899&pgnum=245