# What are the Halachot of Tznius as they relate to men?

Tags: halacha, tznius-modesty, men-male

What are the Halachot of Tznius as they relate specifically to men.  Not men in relation to women.  In other words, I'm *not* looking for "Men must act in a certain way when around women," I'm looking for "Men should act a certain way regardless of whom they're with."

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14638/4682

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7981/759

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37377/759

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37900/759

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30802/why-swim-fully-clothed#comment78780_30814

Comment: Hilchos Hangas Adom ,see Shulchan Aruch

Comment: Please see the comments on the answer and [edit] the question to clarify the latter.

Comment: http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/738955/Rabbi_Aryeh_Lebowitz/Ten_Minute_Halacha_-_Tzenius_For_Men

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47360/759

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=920&st=&pgnum=319

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/75354/759

Comment: See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/84038

Comment: See article in Techumin 39

Answer (score 2):

see the Rama in the beginning of Orach Chaim which says one must feel constantly abashed in G-d's presence. These are the words of the More Nevuchim part 3 chapter 52, see there, and see also later on, and the Sefer Chasidim siman 35 (from Marpe Lenefesh commentary of shaar yichud ch.10)

Comment: Don't these all apply to women too?

Comment: @DoubleAA from the 2nd half i think it fits his basic intention. I'm looking for "Men should act a certain way regardless of whom they're with." but then again maybe you're right. question needs more clarification

Comment: I think it's pretty clear as is.