# Can men dress in tank tops?

Tags: halacha, clothing, tznius-modesty, men-male

Are men allowed to wear tank tops in public? If not, what are the specific laws of tzniut that men are bound by (with regard to dress)?

Comment: If yes, do you no longer want to know the specific laws of tzniut that men are bound to (with regard to dress)?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38747/759

Comment: @DoubleAA http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=24497 but not really...

Comment: @DoubleAA I most definitely do :)

Comment: @DoubleAA ah I see the duplicate question now. They are quite similar...but still no answer!