# Modesty for Men - Bodybuilding and Judaism

Tags: halacha, tznius-modesty, contemporary-halacha

I have two practical questions concerning Modesty (Tzniut) for men and what Halacha says about it which concerns bodybuilding:

1. Can a man take half-naked pictures of himself (with only shorts or pans on like all bodybuilders do)? If yes, can he post those pictures?
2. What can be Judaism's view on bodybuilding, in general? I suppose it may be negative comparing it to idolatry (obsession with one's body) and cultures of Romans and Greeks.

Comment: You should split it into 1. Men and women 2. Men and modesty (in general) Why would BB be different from running? 2. BB and Judaism.

Comment: Possible duplicate listed at https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38747/759 or https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69097/759 @msh